# Numbers in the arguments of the function ioutil.WriteFile

Tags: go

Programming with Go, I noticed that the function ioutil.WriteFile (from the ioutil library) needs some numbers as arguments. What do these numbers mean?

Example:

`ioutil.WriteFile(file_to_write, []byte(string_to_write), 0644) // what 0644 stands for?`

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode

Comment: They are [UNIX filesystem permission bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These numbers are file permission bits.

To know what these bits means see : [permissions (flags) explained](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/article/unix/command/chmod-permissions-flags-explained-600-0600-700-777-100-etc)